# Excel VBA Progress Bar

Tags: excel, progress-bar, vba

I want to pop up a progress bar when my macro enters in a big loop, so that the user is aware that everything is fine, and the the program is just taking some time to complete a task.

I found [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html) tutorial, followed step by step and everything looks fine (I managed to implement the progress bar of the example without any issue).

But now, of course, I want to change the code of the progress bar to my code. When I do that the problem is that:

a) The progress bar is not disappearing after `UserForm1.Hide`(which is not at the tutorial above, I just figured that this is what I have to call to dismiss the progress bar, but it is not working);

b) When I manually close the progress bar once it is 100%, the macro takes about 10 seconds to continue to run the code.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

```
Sub myCode()

    '... long code here

    Dim pctCompl As Single
    UserForm1.Show

    Dim base As Double
    For base = 2 To numberOfLines
        '...some code here too
        pctCompl = (numberOfLines - 2) / numberOfLines
        progress pctCompl
    Next base

    ' Not working.
    UserForm1.Hide

    'Taking too long to open after the progress bar is closed.
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="myPath...", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True

    'Some code here too...

End Sub


Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)

    UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
    UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

    DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: change `UserForm1.Show` to `UserForm1.Show false` , wich allows simultaneous code with your form. (otherwise the code only continues after closing the Userform.

Comment: thanks mate, it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample: [how progressbar works](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Progressbar-How-does-it-68254b8f)

Take look on this. Try to rewrite your cody using my code lines.